# I want to convert an python output list to an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

```py
from os import name
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pathlib import Path

def getNameFromXML():
    for path in Path(".").rglob("*.nfo"):
        tree = ET.parse(path.name)
        root = tree.getroot()

        movieDate = root[4].text.replace("-", ".")
        movieName = root[1].text.replace(" ", ".").replace(".-", "") # Replace spaces and slash to "."
        movieQuality = "1080p" # Movie quality
        movieExt = ".mp4" # Movie Ext
        fullMovieName = "Company." + movieDate + "." + movieName +  "." + movieQuality + movieExt
        
        print(fullMovieName) # This prints the list
```

The output is this:

```
# Output in console
Company.00.00.00.moviename.1080p.mp4
Company.00.00.00.moviename.1080p.mp4
Company.00.00.00.moviename.1080p.mp4
```

I want to convert that in an array to let me grab every one in a "for"

Comment: But you are printing a string, not a list

Comment: Oh, im new in this, but how convert that into a list?

Comment: `fullMovieName.split('.')` ? Also use snake case instead of camel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
from os import name
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pathlib import Path

def getNameFromXML():
    myList=[]
    for path in Path(".").rglob("*.nfo"):
        tree = ET.parse(path.name)
        root = tree.getroot()

        movieDate = root[4].text.replace("-", ".")
        movieName = root[1].text.replace(" ", ".").replace(".-", "") # Replace spaces and slash to "."
        movieQuality = "1080p" # Movie quality
        movieExt = ".mp4" # Movie Ext
        fullMovieName = "Company." + movieDate + "." + movieName +  "." + movieQuality + movieExt
        
        myList.append(fullMovieName)

    return myList

myList = getNameFromXML()
print(myList)
print(myList[1])
```

You can create a list and return it from the function, then use it like "array".
You can learn about Lists in Python from documentations.